# How to get Android TV app listed in Entertainment Apps on home screen?

Tags: android-tv

I had my first Android TV app go live last night, but it has to be searched for in Google Play. How do you get your app listed in the Entertainment Apps section of the Home screen (and in the Google Play Store on Android TV) so people can actually find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Entertainment Apps section does not include all Android TV apps like I had thought. It is a curated list. So unfortunately that means Android TV apps have the same likelihood to be discovered as regular Android apps, and it makes the Andoid TV ecosystem look much smaller to the user than it (presumably) is. I guess I was expecting something more like Roku's channel store.

Comment: Where did you get that information? Did you try to set your app category to Entertainment?

Comment: First of all, it seems obvious that there is just a very small subset of possible apps listed there. But the information was gathered from a discussion on the Google+ Android TV Developer Group.